# There are indispensable VisualStudio workloads to work with cuda C?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, installation

I've recently started a cuda c programming course and I need to install Visual Studio so I would like to know what are the essential workloads to work with the CUDA toolkit 10.1, does anyone know?

My internet connection is not the best and the download would be very large if I select all the workloads

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cuda-10-is-now-available-with-support-for-the-latest-visual-studio-2017-versions/), we can know that CUDA 10 is now available, with support for the latest Visual Studio 2017 versions.

Please download VS 2017 and select the workload ‘**Desktop development with C++**’ and individual component ‘**VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools**’ to install.

After that, download and install [CUDA toolkit 10.1](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads), open VS and go to File-New-Project and choose to create a CUDA project as below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answer my question, it was exactly what I was looking for!.

Comment: You are welcome and It's my pleasure to help you :)